# Barba.js & GSAP new element appears before old element is gone

Tags: gsap, barbajs

I'm trying to implement the basic GSAP fade-in / fade-out demo from the barber.js site.

The markup of test page one is as follows:

```
<body style="background-color: red; color: white;" data-barba="wrapper" data-barba="page1">
    <h3>Constant</h3>
    <main data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="home">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
    <a href="barba2.php" title="go to gae 2">go to page 2</a>
</main>
```

The markup of test page 2 is as follows:

```
<body style="background-color: white; color: red;" data-barba="page2">
    <h3>Constant</h3>
    <main data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="home">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
    <a href="barba1.php" title="go to gae 1">go to page 1</a>
</main>
```

With the following JS at each the bottom of each page:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.3.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@barba/core"></script>
<script>
    barba.init({
        //sync: true,
        transitions: [{
            name: 'opacity-transition',
            leave(data) {
            return gsap.to(data.current.container, {
                opacity: 0

            });
            },
            enter(data) {
            return gsap.from(data.next.container, {
                opacity: 0
            });
            }
        }]
    });
</script>
```

When leaving the current page the old element fades out OK, however the new element appears underneath a fraction early meaning I have two  elements the new one jumping up as the old finishes disappearing?

Is there a way for the new one only to start appearing after the old one has finished?

Comment: I am currently having the same problem, have you figured out a solution?

Comment: Nope sorry, I have not.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, the basic example is kinda failed. It turns out it depends on the styles a bit.
I managed to make it work adding `display: 'none'` to the leave transition, that forces the previous container to disappear before the next starts displaying:

```
// ...
leave(data) {
    return gsap.to(data.current.container, {
        opacity: 0,
        display: 'none',
    });
 }
 // ...
```

My best guess: the transition is meant to allow container overlapping. So you could get away with css (`position: relative` or something like that).

Comment: Yes you're right, why the hell they don't add `display: 'none'`?